# Publish actions to a facebook page's wall with FB JS SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook

I use purely FB JavaScript SDK - most stuff done with **FB.login** and **FB.api**. 
Let's suppose I have a user who granted me permissions for "**publish_actions**" and "**manage_pages**".
This same user has decided that he would rather want the app to publish actions to his page's wall and not his private profile. I have the ID of that page, too.

Is it possible to publish actions to a page's wall with this setting? Using FB.api()?

Comment: Strange. Ok, my actions are not approved yet. But, I need to test them on a page. Each time I make a request to ".../page_id/myapp:myaction..." the action gets published on my (user's) timeline and not the page's timeline. Will it work correctly once the actions are approved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to publish actions to a page's wall

No. Open Graph actions are supposed to be undertaken by “real” people, not pages.

And since, they will be published on the personal profile of the user that undertakes them.

Comment: ok. thank you. My users are businesses that would like to automatically publish to their FB-page's wall when they publish content on my platform. Its a shame this doesn't work - thanks anyway.

Comment: @witwit you can make a share on businesses FB-page's wall

Comment: @ShpatFerizi what do you mean? My solution is to post a "similar" feed message on the wall (instead of an action). Or do you mean I can share the action on the page's wall somehow?

Comment: @witwit, apparently you can't publish an action as page, but you can post on Page's Wall (feed) via your app, more like you can share the link on the page's wall via your app. This is what I mean. I don't think you can share the action!